# Continuous function on a closed interval is integrable proof

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reviewing my prof's slides in which he proves that a continuous function on a closed interval is integrable.

He has defined:

> $m_i=\inf\{f(x) : x\in[t_{i-1}, t_i]\}$
>
> $M_i=\sup\{f(x) : x\in[t_{i-1}, t_i]\}$

In the proof, he says:

> $\displaystyle|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}\ \forall x, y\in[t_{i-1}, t_i]$
>
> $\displaystyle\therefore M_i-m_i\le\frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}$

How did he get the second step from the first? In particular, how did $<$ become $\le$?

Answer (score 1):

Each interval $[t_{i-1},t_i]$ is compact, and the restriction of $f$ to it is still continuous, so we can use the extreme value theorem to deduce that actually there exist $x,y \in [t_{i-1},t_i]$ such that $f(x) = M_i$ and $f(y) = m_i$.  The bound on $M_i - m_i$ then follows from the first bound, and there's no need to switch from $<$ to $\le$.  I'd guess the swap is just a typo, though it's certainly not incorrect.